# Simple class definition giving "missing 1 required positional argument" in ipython

Tags: python, class

Here is my class file (called myclasses.py):

```
class wave:
    def __init__(self, name = "", xdelta = 1)
        self.name = name
        self.xdelta = xdelta

    def loadbinary(bpath):
        print(bpath)
```

For now I've stripped out other details (loading binary file code, etc.) to just this, and when I run the following I'm getting an error output:

```
import myclasses
a = myclasses.wave
a.loadbinary('TEST')
```

The Error:

```
TypeError: loadbinary() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bpath'
```

I've tried changing the loadbinary definition to "loadbinary(self, bpath)" but then it gives the same error. I've also tried replacing the "print" code with just "pass" to have it do nothing, but this still gives me the error. I've also tried running the following:

```
a.loadbinary(bpath='TEST')
```

...but this changes the error to read: loadbinary() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

At this point, I'm not sure what is going on. The class definition is basic, and does not inherit from other classes, and from all I can tell is following the code in the python documentation for classes shown here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

I'm using Python 3.4.3, and this happens in iPython 3.1.0, running in PyCharm 4.5.1. If I run it in iPython 3.1.0 directly at the command prompt (OS X Terminal) I get the following error output:

```
unbound method loadbinary() must be called with wave instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Comment: Why is `loadbinary` in a class at all? Should it be an instance method (i.e. first parameter `self`, called on an instance)? A class method (decorated with `@classmethod`, first parameter `cls`, called on the class)? A static method (decorated with `@staticmethod`, no class/instance parameter)? Or just a function (same as a static method but outside a class). Without more information about **why** you're doing this it's hard to help.

Comment: Adding `self` to the `loadbinary()` parameters fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I tried running your class code and got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on the second line. Are you transcribing this code from memory? Please just copy-paste directly - it's possible you introduced additional errors, or even omitted the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Either that or decorate `loadbinary()` with `@staticmethod` depending on the question if `loadbinary()` needs to manipulate `wave` *objects* or if it is supposed to be a class method.

Comment: If `loadbinary(bpath)` truly just does `print(bpath)` it should be decorated with `@staticmethod`

Comment: @Jkdc, it won't ultimately do only these simple things. I've got a bunch of file loading and parsing tasks to do, but began stripping down the function as it was giving me these errors, to where I finally just attempted to have it print the arguments for the sake of debugging. Didnt even think of the problem being in how I was calling the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never instantiated the class. Do this instead:

```
class wave:
    def __init__(self, name = "", xdelta = 1)
        self.name = name
        self.xdelta = delta

    def loadbinary(self, bpath):
        print(bpath)
```

Or...

```
class wave:
    def __init__(self, name = "", xdelta = 1)
        self.name = name
        self.xdelta = delta

    @staticmethod
    def loadbinary(bpath):
        print(bpath)
```

Then...

```
import myclasses
a = myclasses.wave() # the brackets instantiate the class
a.loadbinary('TEST')
```

Comment: @Kevin, Ahh... That's True! Time for a fix!

Comment: Aaaahhh!!! Yes that's it...oh man! I've been tearing my hair out (and I'm bald) all over a missed set of parentheses. Thanks for the alternative ways to define the class as well. I'm clearly new and am making nuance mistakes. :D

Comment: shouldn't static method work without instantiation?